# Error when parsing NSDate from NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdateformatter

My app freezes when I tap a row, here is the code for `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, the `stringDate` is equal to a string like this: `Feb 4`.

```
EditView *editController = [[EditView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:editController animated:YES];

NSDictionary *cellValue = [self.array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
editController.savedString = [cellValue objectForKey:@"label"];

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *stringDate = [cellValue valueForKey:@"date"];

NSDate *parsedDate = [df dateFromString:stringDate];
editController.savedDate = parsedDate;

[editController release];

[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

I get this error when tapping the row, on the line `NSString *stringDate = [cellValue valueForKey:@"date"];` with this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: date'

**UPDATE:** The parsed date is set to a `UIDatePicker` with date & time mode, and I am simply converting the string date to a `NSDate` to be used with `[timePicker setDate:savedDate animated:YES];`

I created `cellValue` as a `NSDictionary` which basically accesses a `plist` where I created a `NSDictionary` and then wrote it with a formatted `NSString`. And `array` displays the `plist` array, so I can access it using `[cellValue objectForKey:@"date"]`

```
NSDictionary *cellValue = [self.array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```

Comment: What happens, if u use `NSString *stringDate = [cellValue objectForKey:@"date"];`

Comment: btw: I would create a NSDate, when I create the object you return as cellValue.

Comment: I tried using `objectForKey` but it doesn't work, now though I generated an output of the raw date `2012-02-04 16:36:50 +0000` instead of simply `Feb 4`. Then I used `valueForKey` and `objectForKey` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: see my answer: you are not setting an actual format

Comment: Are you sure it is saved as a string? I got the impression, it is already a NSDate object

Comment: What is the output of `NSLog(@"stringDate is '%@'",stringDate);`?

Comment: I added the log to my code but the app crashes before it gives the output.

Comment: you will have to show the code, how you create cellValue

Comment: sorry for the delay, I just updated my question.

Comment: Please give us the code, how you create the object, that you reference as cellValue

Comment: you mean how I am referencing `indexPath.row` to my plist?

Comment: I figured out why I get this error. The string with the date value is not right. The string `Feb 4` can't be parsed so I need a full date, like `2012-02-04 16:36:50 +0000` for it too work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to teach the formatter the format your string fulfills

It should be something like:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MMM d"];
```